# My 1-line if-else statement isn't working

Tags: c++

Any idea why my console is printing out "1" ??? It should be printing an actual statement.

(Just so you know, I'm making a program that evaluates a math expression representing by a string. Right now I'm at the part where it checks to make sure it's a valid expression.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

char eqarr[] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '~', '|', '*', '^', '(', ')'};

const std::set<char> eqset(eqarr, eqarr + sizeof(eqarr)/sizeof(char));

bool valid_equation(std::string);


int main (int argc, char* const argv[]) {

    std::string str("4^3^~2");
    std::cout << valid_equation(str) ? "Yep, that equation workss." : "No, that equation doesn't work";


    return 0;
}

bool valid_equation(std::string S) { 
    // Make one iteration through the characters of S to check whether it's a valid equation 
    for (std::set<char>::const_iterator it = eqset.begin(); it != eqset.end(); ++it) {
        // Check that *it is one of the possible characters in an equation
        if (eqset.count(*it) == 0) { 
            std::cout << "Invalid character: " << *it << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
    }


    return true;
}
```

Comment: You're not iterating through the characters of the string.  You're iterating through the characters in the set (and checking for their membership in the set, which is a bit redundant).

Comment: As Benjamin noted, your function completely ignores the string. It checks whether the set contains the lements of the very same set. This is a tautology. The function will always evaluate to `true`. It is also not clear why you decided to use `count` to verify whether an element belongs to the set. `find` would be more straightforward and a bit more efficient.

Comment: WHOOPS! BIG TYPE-O ON MY PART! That's supposed to be iterating through S.

Answer (score 9):

The `<<` operator has higher precedence than the ternary operator `?:`, so the line is equivalent to:

```
(std::cout << valid_equation(str)) ? "Yep, that equation workss." : "No, that equation doesn't work";
```

So it's just outputting the result of `valid_equation(str)` which is a `bool` and then doing nothing with the string literals.

You'll need to use some brackets:

```
std::cout << (valid_equation(str) ? "Yep, that equation workss." : "No, that equation doesn't work");
```

Answer (score 0):

Precedence of operator `<<` is higher than ternary operator. Hence the statement is equivalent to:

```
(std::cout << valid_equation(str)) ? "Yep, that equation works." : "No, that equation doesn't work";
```

So you need to put parentheses around the ternary operator, like this

```
   std::cout << (valid_equation(str) ? "Yep, that equation works." : "No, that equation doesn't work");
```

Interestingly the program as you wrote it is *syntactically* correct (hence your confusion when it compiles fine, and prints 1)! This is because of two interesting properties of ostream class:

1) The [overloaded bitwise left shift operator (`<<`) in ostream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/) has a return type of `ostream&`

2) The [objects of ostream class can be converted to a boolean value](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/operator_bool/).

What happens is this: first the `std::cout << valid_equation(str)` is executed, which prints value `1` on stdout (as `valid_equation(str)` returned `true`), then the rest of the statement is reduced to:

```
(An object of ostream type) ? "Yep, that equation workss." : "No, that equation doesn't work";
```

which due to property (2), becomes:

```
(a boolean value) ? "Yep, that equation workss." : "No, that equation doesn't work";
```

Which is a valid (although wasteful) C++ statement, and its value is a `const char*` pointing to either one of the two strings (depending on the boolean conversion of the `ostream` object). To see this in action try changing it to this line for fun:

```
 std::cout << (std::cout << valid_equation(str) ? "Yep, that equation workss." : "No, that equation doesn't work");
```